# Let $L:V \to W$ be a linear transformation between two vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $L:V \to W$ be a linear transformation between two vector spaces. Prove that if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent, but $L(v_1)$ and $L(v_2)$ are not, then there is a nonzero vector in the kernel of $L$.

> How to prove this? Suppose the kernel of $L$ contains only zero vector, so we prove a contradiction, but how proceed? And how to use given condition?

Answer (score 4):

If $L(v_1)$ and $L(v_2)$ are linearly dependent, then there are scalars $s,t$ such that

$0=sL(v_1)+tL(v_2)$ and $(s,t) \ne (0,0)$.

since $L$ is linear, we get

$0=L(sv_1+tv_2)$ . Therefore $sv_1+tv_2$ is in the kernel of $L$

Why do we have $sv_1+tv_2 \ne 0$ ?

Answer (score 2):

If $L(v_1)$ and $L(v_2)$ are linearly dependent, then say $L(v_1)=\alpha L(v_2)$ for some scalar $\alpha.$ By linearity $L(v_1-\alpha v_2)=0,$ so $v_1-\alpha V_2$ is in the kernel of $L.$

Answer (score 1):

$L(v_1)$ and $L(v_2)$ are dependent so there are non zero $c\in F$ such that $L(v_1)=cL(v_2)$. By linearity,
$$
L(v_1-cv_2) = 0 \implies v_1-cv_2 \in \text{Ker}(L).
$$
Because $v_1$ and $v_2$ linearly independent then if $ v_1-cv_2 = 0$ implies that $c=0$. Contradict with assumption $c\neq 0$. So $v_1-cv_2  \neq 0$, that is there are non zero vector in kernel $L$.